SQL cumulative sum of dates and calculate the number of sessions in time duration
I am stuck with a sql to reset a cumulative sum of time after reaching duration of 20 minutes and calculate the difference between  date time column and reset time.. I'm not sure if it's possible and other examples I've found are slightly different than mine.
I need to calculcuate the number of sessions that happens

when login's first time in the day
time duration of current and previous date time is greater than 20 minutes
cummulative sum of time duration is greater than 20 minutes.

The source data looks like (date time colum and UserID)
Pick_Date_time        userID   
2024-10-01 03:00:00     A1      
2024-10-01 03:05:43     A1        
2024-10-01 03:07:10     A1        
2024-10-01 03:11:12     B1
2024-10-01 03:13:15     B1
2024-10-01 04:21:10     A1       
2024-10-01 04:26:23     A1
2024-10-01 04:35:12     A1
2024-10-01 04:42:15     A1
2024-10-01 04:56:10     A1
2024-10-01 04:04:12     B1 

Output Wanted
Pick_Date_time        userID   SessionID
2024-10-01 03:00:00     A1      1   --> first record of the day
2024-10-01 03:05:43     A1      0
2024-10-01 03:07:10     A1      0   --> cumm time duration < 20 min for A1 user 
2024-10-01 03:11:12     B1      1   --> first record of the day
2024-10-01 03:13:15     B1      0   --> time duration < 20 min for B1 user
2024-10-01 04:21:10     A1      1   --> time diff of current val and previous val is > 20
2024-10-01 04:26:23     A1  5min 0   --> starting cumm time duration
2024-10-01 04:35:12     A1  12min 0  --> calcuate until cumm time duration < 20 minutes
2024-10-01 0:39:12     B1      1    --> time diff b/w curr val and previous val > 20 so sessionID =1
2024-10-01 0:41:03     B1  1min 0  --> cumm sum from previous val for B1 User
2024-10-01 0:42:10     B1  2min 0  --> cumm sum from previous val for B1 User
2024-10-01 04:42:15     A1  21 min 1 --> cumm time > 20min SessionID =1
2024-10-01 04:47:10     A1  5min 0-->  reseting the previous datetime 
to 2024-10-01 04:42:15 until we reach 20 minutes duration
2024-10-01 04:49:12     A1  7min 0 --> cumm sum from reset value .


I was able to solve first 2 scenarios using LAG and window functions but couldn't resolve the 3 scenario to calculate the cummulative sum and reset the date time.
Appreciate your help
Thanks

In your example a new session for A1 starts at 04:21 but, according to your calculations, the cummulative time for this user at 04:42 is 16 mins. Should it not be 21 minutes?

my bad, Thanks @JesusDiazRivero, fixed the sample data

Try use recursive  CTE.

What query have you tried (that solves first 2 scenarios)., please include it in your question.

I suggest using a lateral join e,g, https://dbfiddle.uk/NTulDmIQ

@AdrianMaxwell, your offer is tempting in its simplicity, but it may give the wrong answer. See example (https://dbfiddle.uk/cLnifddt)

Perhaps you could include the expected result in the question. But also note I was suggesting a technique, not a fully developed solution.
